# Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-security-manager

I get an error when starting my spring-boot application. The exception occurs in combination with the `java secuirity manager´.

```
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
        at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
        at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:182)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1368)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Starting the project directly with IntelliJ-IDE works perfectly fine, but when i use terminal `java -jar java -jar 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the above exception.

I already tried to add maven dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-logging` additional to `spring-boot-starter-web`, but that didn't resolve the problem. Also deleting .m2 and reinstalling all packages didn't help.

Maven-dependencies are all on the latest stable version.

***pom.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

***Main.java***

```java
...
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() throws UnknownHostException {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManagerImpl());
}
...
```

Comment: In short, your dependencies are a mess, clean thenm up.

Comment: Also register the security manager in your `main` method, before the `SpringApplication.run`. not as an eventlistener.

Answer (score -1):

In short,  your dependencies are a mess. Logback is provided by Spring and several others are already included through the starters. Spring Boot will also manage version of other dependencies, use those to be sure to get a proper one. Finally I suggest depending on the default, HikariCP, connection pool instead of Commons DBCP2.

So again in short cleanup your dependencies.

```xml
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: @m-deinum Thank you for your time, but changing dependencies and moving the `SecurityManager` to the `main` method didn't solve the problem.